# What is the current stance of the Greek ΣΥΡΙΖΑ government on CETA?

Tags: greece, ceta

The social-democratic regional government of Wallonia, Belgium initially blocked CETA but has now [apparently backed it](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-37788882).  Reportedly, all other EU governments agree on CETA.  This surprises me.  In 2014, [the Greek governing ΣΥΡΙΖΑ stated](http://www.guengl.eu/group/delegation_news/eu-syriza-delegation-announcement-about-ceta):

> The SYRIZA Delegation categorically opposes the ratification of these agreements and calls the Greek population to participate in the pan-European mobilisation against TTIP and CETA on the 11th of October 2014.

When I search for SYRIZA CETA, I find mostly old results, but I only search in English.  Is there any more recent statement from the Greek ΣΥΡΙΖΑ government on CETA?  Do they back it now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Greek government [back it now.](http://www.economywatch.gr/economy-minister-stathakis-greek-positions-on-ceta-deal-taken-into-account-by-eu/)

It doesn't go into detail but says

> the EU now has “a framework of safeguards that will protect the [European acquis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acquis_communautaire) and take into account of the concerns of civil society.”

which implies that there was sufficient compromise to make them happy that Greek interests will be protected. The other possibility, of course, is that they were browbeaten into agreeing but no-one would admit that even if true.